# Mitigar el uso de tablas temporal en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

El uso de tablas temporales dentro de los procedimientos almacenados, me genera cierto tipo de retrasos a causa de que en tiempos de ejecución se realizarián 3 tareas para llegar al cumplirse el objetivo.
Tengo el siguiente código para conocer cuál es el costo de un artículo vendido basado en el último pedido(es funcional), lo que requiero hacer es evitar que se realicen 3 proceso, requiero una query que no use tablas temporales pero que me de el mismo resultado.

que puedo ajustar de esta query para obtener el mismo resultado

```
create table #temp_consult
            (
                pre_costo decimal(18,0)
            )

insert into #temp_consult
select (
            select top 1 dp.valor_unitario from detalle_pedido dp
            where df.articuloid = dp.articuloid
            order by dp.id_detalle_pedido desc
        ) pre_costo

from detalle_factura df
where id_factura = 661374

select sum(pre_costo) from #temp_consult
drop table #temp_consult
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bueno si a alguien tiene el mismo inconveniente, pude resolverlo aplicando un sum sobre la subconsulta como origen, de esta manera

```
select sum(pre_costo) as costo
 from(
        select (
                    select top 1 dp.valor_unitario from detalle_pedido dp
                    where df.articuloid = dp.articuloid
                    order by dp.id_detalle_pedido desc
                ) pre_costo

        from detalle_factura df
        where id_factura = 661374
) as costo
```